# Copying shell file to path

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to WSL and Linux, but I'm trying to follow installation instructions for rhasspy (https://rhasspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/#windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl). I have run the `make install` command successfully and the next step says I should copy rhasspy somewhere in my path but I can't quite figure out what *copying* to path means.

> When installation is finished, copy rhasspy.sh somewhere in your PATH and rename it to rhasspy.

I added it to path but nothing changed so I was wondering if there is something I'm doing wrong. Right now when I run rhasspy on wsl it says `rhasspy.sh: command not found`. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it says is, put it in some place where the system will look for it when you type its name without full path in the shell.

There is an environment variable `PATH` that contains all those locations, separated by a `:`. (Check out `echo $PATH`.)

So, the author of these instructions leaves it up to you whether...

1. You want to copy the file to a location of your choice that is already in the `PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`.

   Usually `~/bin` is a good choice because it is per-user and doesn't pollute the system.

   (Note that the directory `~/bin` is added to the `PATH` by your `.profile` file only if it exists, so if you don't have this directory yet and create it now, you need to start a new login shell or run `. ~/.profile`<sup>1</sup> before you can use it.)

- OR -

2. You want to create a new directory specifically for this application (say for example `~/opt/rhasspy`) and append that directory to the `PATH` variable.

   This can be done by adding the line `export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/rhasspy` to your `~/.profile` file. Then, start a new login shell or reload the file using `. ~/.profile`<sup>1</sup> for the changes to take effect.

   If the directory in which this file is currently located is OK for you to keep permanently, then you can also just add *that* directory to the `PATH` instead of creating a new one.

**Note:** The `PATH` always contains *directory paths* in which the shell will look for executable files. It does *not* contain the actual *file paths*!

---

<sub>**1:** Yes, technically it is "cleaner" to log into a new shell or to run that one `export` statement manually instead of using `. ~/.profile` because the latter will apply things a second time that were already done before, so for example it can end up with the same directory in the `PATH` multiple times in the current session. In most cases that is fine though.</sub>

Comment: An alternative that I prefer, because I don't like a cluttered home directory, is to extend the XDG specified "$HOME/.local/share" in the obvious way to use additional subdirectories of "$HOME/.local" -- including  "bin", "lib", and "opt". The "$HOME/.profile" logon script in Ubuntu adds "$HOME/.local/bin" to `PATH` if the directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is an environment variable. When you launch `env`, you see the list of known environment variables on your system.

In order to add something to your `PATH` variable, you need to take the variable, add the mentioned directory (preceeded by a semi-colon, most probably, as a separator) and store this again as the `PATH` variable. This can be done as follows (own example):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/this_user
```

Comment: I was wondering if adding something to path is the same as copying something to path?

Comment: Be careful: you always need to append something to path, or you might cause your system not to work anymore. What are your PATH variable and what is the directory you're referring to? I'll see how to make a new PATH variable.

Answer (score -1):

the `"PATH"` it is referring to in linux is just inside the folder called `/usr/bin`. when you type a command into the terminal it looks for a program with that name inside the location. im not sure if this is the `PATH` you are looking for but hope it helps

Comment: `/usr/bin` is usually _in_ the `PATH` but it _is_ not the `PATH`.

Comment: You misunderstood me, it's the other way round. Try `echo $PATH` to see what I mean. `/usr/bin` is **one of the directories** that are usually set in the `PATH` variable. But that variable and some directory are not the same thing.

Comment: @CherryDT yes i understand what you mean now but what i was trying to say was that the program should go into one of those folders that are in PATH and not actually be added to PATH.

Comment: Yes that's true but your answer sounds just like `/usr/bin` is the only directory in the path 